# Select Next Not Same Data Row in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a table with two columns. Now I wanted to select the row which is "Less" than previous one. For eg.

A | B

2 | 1

2 | 2

2 | 4

2 | 8

2 | 9

3 | 12

3 | 14

1 | 16

I want to select the row with "1" in **a** since it's less than previous 3. I can do it by making new column but looking for something inplace.

Comment: Can I ask why it needs to be done without making a new column?  This seems like an arbitrary restriction?  What about using a temporary column/temporary array?  These exist for the duration for the datastep but are not saved to the output dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data want;
set have;
by a notsorted;
if first.a then flag=ifn(a lt lag(a),1,0);  *ifn allows lag to work here - excel style if;
run;
```

That will identify rows that are the first row in a set, and have a value of a that is less than the previous value of a.  You can then filter `want` by `flag=1`.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Is it possible to Have "3" as macro variable so we can comapre the next row.

Comment: No, it's not possible in a useful sense to make it a macro variable.  What are you trying to do with it?  It can certainly become a data step variable, for example.